# How to remove a value from a specific property in a JSON string by matching value?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, json.net

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"Country":"USA","States":["Chicago","Miami"]}

public string Remove(string json)
{
    string[] stateFilter = { "Chicago", "Miami"};
    foreach (var state in stateFilter)
    {
        //here I would like to create new copy of json for each state.
        string newJson = {"Country":"USA","States":["Chicago"]}  // Removed Miami from json for Chicago
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create a new JSON string for each state by finding the state in the JSON and removing it from the JSON string.  So each state will contain its new copy of the JSON and will not contain any other state.

For example: Chicago will contain `Chicago` in JSON `States` Property.

Code I am trying:

```
public string Remove(string json)
{
    string[] stateFilter = { "Chicago", "Miami"};
    foreach (var state in stateFilter)
    {
        var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);

        jArr.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Name == state)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(att => att.Remove());
    }
}
```

But the above code removes the property instead of the value from the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

This solution based on your specification: *So each state will contain its new copy of json and will not contain any other state*

You can use `Newtonsoft` json serializer to deserialize json create new instance for every state and serialize them back to json

```
public class States
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> States { get; set; }        
}

public IEnumerable<string> GenerateSeparatedListOfStates(string json)
{
    var original = JsonConvert.DeserializaeObject<States>(json);

    foreach(string state in original.States)
    {
        var temp = new States 
        { 
            Country = state.Country,
            States = new List<string> { state }
        }
        yield return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but actually my json string contains lots of properties but for sake of simplicity I haven't  listed those properties because that was not needed that is why am not deserializing json string to class to avoid adding unnecessary overhead of deserializing.isnt this possible without deserializing???

Comment: If I understand right you want create separated `json` for every state in the `States` array.  So you need to copy your original `json` for every state anyway. Deserialization doing same job as you trying to do manually - reading a string and create objects. Did you notice performance issue/difference when you use serialization approach?

Comment: But as i said that i have lots of properties so i was avoiding to create class and deserializing in to class but now i realize that it wont be possible without deserializing in to class.am i right??

Comment: It can be possible without deserialization, but then you need read/create json by yourself. And I am not sure that "manual" approach will be faster or more readable. You need create class for all properties of json only once -then use it. There are different utilities which generates c# class based on json [http://json2csharp.com/](http://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You need  deserialize your json into object, remove the object which you don't need from the States List and after that serialize it again.

```
    public class JsonClass
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public List<string> States { get; set; }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{""Country"":""USA"",""States"":[""Chicago"",""Miami""]}";

        JsonClass className  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(json);

        className.States.Remove("Miami");

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(className));

    }
```

**Edit:**

About your question: remove all elements without Chicago:

Change line:

```
className.States.Remove("Miami");
```

To:

```
className.States.RemoveAll(x => x != "Chicago");
```

Comment: Sorry but actually my json string contains lots of properties but for sake of simplicity I haven't  listed those properties because that was not needed that is why am not deserializing json string to class to avoid adding unnecessary overhead of deserializing.isnt this possible without deserializing???

Comment: @Learning So what is the problem if you add all the properties ? This is the correct way of doing it. It is prompt to less errors.

Comment: Can you show that how to conditionally remove miami.You have hardcoded miami value.i have a loop on my state and suppose i have 3 - 4 states then how do i provide this condition in remove method.Can you please show that in your answer?

Comment: @Learning can you tell which State you want to delete, what is the exact condition of the state to be deleted. I don't understand the requirement of deletion. You have 20 states for an example, which one should be deleted and why ?

Comment: Suppose i am creating new json for chicago state then i would like to delete all 19 other states except chicago.Same way if i am creating new json for miami then i would like to delete all other 19 states except miami because currently i am creating new json for miami

Answer (score 1):

I've read all your question and all the comments to the other answers, and quite frankly I'm still unsure if this will answer what I think you are asking!

This code does not require any external library, you simply need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` to your project.

```
string jsonString = "{\"Country\":\"USA\",\"States\":[\"Chicago\",\"Miami\"]}";
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic json = jss.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
var statesToRemove = new object[] { "Chicago", "Miami" };
object[] originalStates = json["States"] as object[];
foreach(var state in statesToRemove)
{
    json["States"] = new[] { state }; 
    string newJson = jss.Serialize(json);
}
// Outputs...
// {"Country":"USA","States":["Chicago"]}
// {"Country":"USA","States":["Miami"]}
```

We deserialize the json to an object graph and traverse it dynamically (using `dynamic` - this is how `json["States"]` even compiles). For each state in the statesToRemove collection, we serialize a new json string with that as the only state.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a way to copy the JSON and replace the `States` array with just a single, known state, you could make your method like this:

```
public static string Remove(string json, string stateToKeep)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    jo["States"] = new JArray(stateToKeep);
    return jo.ToString();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hVz6yF

If you're looking to do this for all the states in the `States` array without knowing in advance what they all are, you could do something like this instead:

```
public static string Remove(string json)
{
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    var result = obj["States"].Select(s =>
    {
        var clone = s.Root.DeepClone();
        clone["States"] = new JArray(s);
        return clone;
    });
    return new JArray(result).ToString();
}
```

Basically, we parse the JSON to a `JObject`, then iterate over the states using `Select`.  For each state, we clone the entire JSON, then replace the clones' `States` array with a new `JArray` containing just the single state.  Lastly, we put all these clones into a new `JArray` and convert it to string.

Given your original JSON, you would end up with this new result:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "USA",
    "States": [
      "Chicago"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Country": "USA",
    "States": [
      "Miami"
    ]
  }
]
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qb4fu0

Comment: Can you please tell me that what would be the performance difference between derializing json string in to class then finding and removing data from it and then again serializing in to json string as 2 above answers are doing??

Comment: I don't know; it probably depends on the size of the JSON.  You would have to try that yourself and measure it in your environment to find out what performs better.

Comment: Actually size of json is long like it contains lots of properties but i am just concerned with States property but still upvoted your answer for your kind efforts towards helping me.I really appreciate it